# Cannot GET /api/addmasterlist on app.post

Tags: node.js, express

server.js

```
var express         = require('express');
var mysql           = require('mysql');
var app             = express();                  
var morgan          = require('morgan');          
var bodyParser      = require('body-parser');     
var methodOverride  = require("method-override");
var request         = require("request");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                       
app.use(morgan('combined'));                                             
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended' : 'true'}));                
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                           
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json'}));        
app.use(methodOverride());

var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host     : 'localhost',
    port     : 3306,
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'xxxxxxx',
    database : 'masterlist',
    debug    :  false
});




//Rest APIs
app.get('/api/fetchmasterlist', function(req, res){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){

        if(!err){

            //Query
            var strquery = "SELECT * FROM students";
            connection.query(strquery, function(err, rows){
                if(err){
                    res.json("Error in Query." + err);
                }else{
                    res.json(rows);
                }
            });


        }else {

            //Return an Error
            connection.release();
            connection.destroy();
            res.json("Error geting connection from DATABASE.");
            return;
        }

    });

});
app.post('/api/addmasterlist', function(req, res){
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){

        if(!err){

            //Query
            /*var post  = req.body.param;*/
            var strquery = "INSERT INTO students(id, studentid, studentname, course, year) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            connection.query(strquery, [req.body.id, req.body.studentid, req.body.studentname, req.body.course, req.body.year], function(err, rows){
                if(err){
                    res.json("Error in Query." + err);
                }else{
                    res.json("Success in inserting the new student." + rows);
                }
            });


        }else {

            //Return an Error
            /*connection.release();
            connection.destroy();*/
            res.json("Error geting connection from DATABASE.");
            return;
        }

    });

});


// application route
app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html') // load the single static file
});



// listen
app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

my api/addmasterlist is not working and it gives me 
Cannot GET /api/addmasterlist
error on the browser
using app.get on the masterlist seems to work fine and reflect on the database the problem is it will not work on my angular.js

okay using app.get seems to work but can anyone help me is this the proper way of pushing through nodejs? using angular

```
$scope.saveNewStudent = function(){
    var dataa =  $scope.studentmasterlist.push({
        id: ($scope.studentmasterlist.length + 1),
        studentid: $scope.studentid,
        studentname: $scope.studentname,
        course: $scope.course,
        year: $scope.year,

    });

 $http.get('/api/addmasterlist', dataa).success(function(data, status) {
    console.log('Data posted successfully');
  })
    //Clear the scope
    $scope.studentid = "";
    $scope.studentname = "";
    $scope.course = "";
    $scope.year = "";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you declared your `/api/addmasterlist` endpoint as a POST request. Try changing it to GET and it might work as you expected.

Change this:

```
app.post('/api/addmasterlist', function(req, res){
```

To this:

```
app.get('/api/addmasterlist', function(req, res){
```

Alternatively, you can change your angular's http from get to post:

Change:

```
$http.get('/api/addmasterlist', dataa).success(function(data, status) {
```

to

```
$http.post('/api/addmasterlist', dataa).success(function(data, status) {
```

Comment: as i mentioned app.get seems to work but my problem is i cant seem to make my app to send data to node this is my code on angular edited* please check post thanks

Comment: Now I believe you are using get in angular instead of post. I edited my answer, check it out

Comment: tried it also and it gives me this

angular.js:12011 POST http://localhost:8080/api/addmasterlist 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Does the /api/fetchmasterlist work fine? When you open it in the browser?

Comment: Out of ideas. I would comment out all unnecessary code and just kept the post route on the server and the post call in the angular and see if it works.